# My programme is showing the following error: 'argument 'length.out' must be of length 1'. I do not think I have made any mistake

Tags: r

I am creating a data for a model in ecology which is called as random fraction model.
The programme for the model:

```
    RelAbund<-randomfraction(3,1000)
```

Its output is:

```
    RelAbund
      [,1]        [,2]
    [1,] 0.6083835 0.004510276
    [2,] 0.2792227 0.003305510
    [3,] 0.1123938 0.002514014
```

Now I want to create data using the first column of this matrix. 
I am storing this data in a list called 'Data'.
It is a list of vectors. The vectors contain consecutive +ve numbers.
e.g. vector1 is (1,2,3,4,5)
     vector2 is(6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13)
     & so on. 
Now the programme I have written to create the data is as follows:

```
    CreateData<-function(nind,nspec)  
    RelAbund<-randomfraction(nspec,1000)                                                                                      
    Data<-list()
    Datavector<-c()
    individuals<-c(0)
    for(ii in 1:nspec-1){
    **individuals<-seq(length.out=RelAbund[ii,1]*nind,from=tail(individuals,n=1)+1,by=1)** 
    Data<-lappend(Data,individuals)
    }
    Datavector<-seq(length=nind-(tail(tail(Data,n=1),n=1)),from=tail(tail(Data,n=1),n=1)+1,by=1)
    Data<-lappend(Data,Datavector)
    return(Data)
    }
```

The starred line is showing error:

Error is as follows:

```
    Error in seq.default(length.out = RelAbund[ii, 1] * nind, from = tail(individuals,  : argument 'length.out' must be of length 1
```

nind is an integer.
Acc to me the argument length.out is already of length 1. 
Then why is it showing this error??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you didn't mean

```
for(ii in 1:(nspec-1)){
  ...
}
```

instead of

```
for(ii in 1:nspec-1){
  ...
}
```

1:nspec-1 will produce a size nspec vector starting at 0.

1:(nspec-1) starts at 1, and is of size nspec-1